# wp_query() function is not showing title

Tags: wordpress

I am working in WordPress and wp_query() function is not bringing posts title from db so please can someone help me??

Here is my code..

```
add_action('admin_menu','wpdocs_register_my_custom_menu_page');
/**
* Register a custom menu page.
*/


function wpdocs_register_my_custom_menu_page(){
        add_menu_page( 
            __( 'Admin Pages', 'textdomain' ),
            'Test Menu',
            'manage_options',
            'custompage',
            'my_custom_menu_page'

        ); 
    }

/**
 * Display a custom menu page
 */


function my_custom_menu_page(){
        esc_html_e( 'Admin Pages', 'textdomain' );  
       global $output;
        $pages = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'page','posts_per_page'=> '-1','post_status'=>'publish'));
        if($pages->have_posts()){
        while($pages->have_posts()){ ?>

            <h2><?php $pages->the_title() ?></h2>

        <?php   $pages->the_post();
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
        }
```

Every effort will be highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before using **the_title()** post must be setup. So use **$pages->the_post()** before displaying title. So please modify code as

```
while($pages->have_posts()){
    $pages->the_posts();
?>
     <h2> <?php the_title(); ?> </h2>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Here is the code
if($pages->have_posts()){
     while($pages->have_posts()){ $pages->the_post(); ?>
      
      <h2><?php $pages->the_title() ?></h2>

     <?php 
     }
 }

Comment: Please don't use $pages->the_title(); use only <?php the_title(); ?>

Comment: Wow!! Working now.
Thanks a lot :) @Mahendra singh